# How to install GDAL Python Bindings for Postgres.app

Tags: python, gdal, postgresapp, gdal-python-bindings

I installed the latest Postgre.app version Version 2.5.6 (139) Universal version for my new MacBook Pro M1. After setting up the CLI tools, I am able to access all gdal binaries that come bundled like `gdalinfo`.

However I also need to install the python bindings to use cli utilities like `gdal2tiles.py`. What's the right way to go about installing these so they work with the rest of gdal bundled with latest Postgress.app?

Current version bundled with Postgres.app is

```sh
➜ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.3.3, released 2021/10/25
```

Postgres.app installs GDAL binaries at:

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin` and currently has the following bundled:

```sh
clusterdb         ecpg              gdal_translate    gdalinfo          gdaltindex        invproj           pg_amcheck        pg_ctl            pg_resetwal       pg_verifybackup   proj              vacuumdb
createdb          gdal-config       gdal_viewshed     gdallocationinfo  gdaltransform     nearblack         pg_archivecleanup pg_dump           pg_restore        pg_waldump        psql              vacuumlo
createuser        gdal_contour      gdaladdo          gdalmanage        gdalwarp          ogr2ogr           pg_basebackup     pg_dumpall        pg_rewind         pgbench           raster2pgsql
cs2cs             gdal_create       gdalbuildvrt      gdalmdiminfo      geod              ogrinfo           pg_checksums      pg_isready        pg_test_fsync     pgsql2shp         reindexdb
dropdb            gdal_grid         gdaldem           gdalmdimtranslate initdb            ogrtindex         pg_config         pg_receivewal     pg_test_timing    postgres          shp2pgsql
dropuser          gdal_rasterize    gdalenhance       gdalsrsinfo       invgeod           oid2name          pg_controldata    pg_recvlogical    pg_upgrade        postmaster        testepsg
```

I realize there are plenty of ways to install gdal with python bindings using brew and pip, but I am looking to do this the right way while utilizing the core gdal that comes with Postgres.app

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [pygdal](https://pypi.org/project/pygdal/), it is made for this exact purpose.

```
export GDALHOME="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest"
pip install pygdal=="`gdal-config --version`.*"
```